# Passing a custom object to a REST endpoint with C#

Tags: c#, rest, webrequest, endpoint

I have a rest endpoint that accepts a single custom object parameter containing two properties.

Let's call the param InfoParam

```
public class InfoParam
{
    public long LongVar { get; set; }
    public string StringVar { get; set; }
}
```

My code I have is as follows:

```
infoParam.LongVar = 12345678;
infoParam.StringVar = "abc"

var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
myRequest.Method = "POST";

var content = string.Empty;

using (var theResponse = (HttpWebResponse)MyRequest.GetResponse())
{
    using (var stream = theResponse.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            content = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

So I have the InfoParam variable, with the two values, but I can't figure out where to pass it in to the REST endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the object into a stream of bytes that can be added to the Request stream - which will in turn be sent as the HTTP POST body.  The format of these bytes needs to match what the server expects.  REST endpoints *usually* expect these bytes to resemble JSON.

```cs
// assuming you have added Newtonsoft.JSON package and added the correct using statements
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(myRequest.GetRequestStream()) {
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(infoParam);
    writer.WriteLine(json);
    writer.Flush();
}
```

You'll probably want to set various other request parameters, like the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: But once I have the json, where do I add it?

Comment: If by "add it" you mean, "how do I have my HttpRequest object send it as part of the HTTP request?" - that's answered above.  If you mean something else then you'll need to clarify your question.

Comment: in the context of the code I posted above, I do not understand where your code goes.

Comment: Ah.  After you create the request and before you ask for a response.

Comment: ok so I did that, but when I inspect the request, I don't see the json we wrote into the stream.

Comment: @ChrisG.Williams: correct.  it's in the stream.  not something one usually inspects.  To check what is being sent to the REST api, use Telerik Fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write it int the `Content (and set content-type). Check out [How to: Send data by using the WebRequest class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-send-data-using-the-webrequest-class)

**The recommendation is to use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` instead.**

Please note that you should know what content the server expects ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, json, etc.)

The following snippet is from [POST JSON data over HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/httpclient#post-json-data-over-http)

```
// Construct the HttpClient and Uri. This endpoint is for test purposes only.
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.contoso.com/post");

        // Construct the JSON to post.
        HttpStringContent content = new HttpStringContent(
            "{ \"firstName\": \"Eliot\" }",
            UnicodeEncoding.Utf8,
            "application/json");

        // Post the JSON and wait for a response.
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(
            uri,
            content);

        // Make sure the post succeeded, and write out the response.
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var httpResponseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(httpResponseBody);
```

In your case the content would be something like this

```
HttpStringContent content = new HttpStringContent(
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(infoParam), // using Json.Net;
            UnicodeEncoding.Utf8,
            "application/json");
```